# how to display object value of multiselect primeng angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

I am following this https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect but docs have only information about to print value of a string. how can I display the object value.  `this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', cityCode: 'NY'}});` for instance i want to display code. I tried {{selectedCity.cityCode}} it is displaying [obj obj]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `selectedCity` is an array, you should use `*ngFor` to loop through the items.

```
<div *ngFor="let city of selectedCities">
  <p>{{city.id}}. {{city.cityCode}} - {{city.name}}</p>
</div>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bgdiVvNG94AthFtX8bSn?p=preview)

Comment: thanks , but why cant I use it as {{ selectedCities.id }}

Comment: Because `selectedCities` is an array, objects in `selectedCities` have `id`, `selectedCities` itself doesn't have any property/attribute `id`

Comment: `cities: SelectItem[];
selectedCity: any;
this.cities = [];
this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}});`  {{selectedCity.id}} can I access like this? or something alternative without *ngFor ?

Comment: Then you have to manually provide object indexes, like `{{selectedCity[0].id}}`, `{{selectedCity[1].id}}`, `{{selectedCity[2].id}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, and one more quick question, there are options of search and select all in multiselect dropdown in ngprime, can we remove them if yes how? [link](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect)

Comment: you can override the `.ui-multiselect-header` class. I have updated the demo, check it out.

Comment: how to override CSS ? i tried this code `::ng-deep .ui-multiselect-header{
  display: none !important;
}` as you did in plunker example. this way is not working , I am new , can you please explain how to override CSS in my code.